# bigquery default time_partitioning_expiration time?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a default "time_partitioning_expiration" time in millseconds that gets set if this parameter is not mentioned during the creation of a partitioned table? Like maybe 24 hours or 72 hours?

The reason i am asking is that, certain major partitions of my day paritioned table got deleted automatically without me doing anything after a day or two.

I tried "bq show --format=prettyjson" in the bq command line and below is what i get. so its clear that variable "time_partitioning_expiration" was not set during creation.

```
},
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY"
  },
  "type": "TABLE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no default value for expirationMs for partitioned table's per partition expiration. If you are able to share the full table reference, I can see if we have the history of the table to see what happened. Alternatively, you may be able to query the audit logs for your project (if enabled) to see operations on the table.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/api/ref_bq/rest/Shared.Types/AuditData

Comment: Hi Pavan, can you update time_partitioning_expiration for an entire partitioned table with the bq cli?

Comment: Nevermind! It looks like it's: `bq update --time_partitioning_expiration 259200000 dataset.table`